# Hide/show MKPolyline with a particular title?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay, google-polyline

How would I hide/show polyline (`MKPolyline`) with a particular title?

I am able to remove them with this code:

```
-(IBAction)hideOverlay:(id)sender
{
for (id<MKOverlay> overlayToRemove in self.mapView.overlays)
 {
    if ([overlayToRemove isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        if ([polyline.title isEqualToString:@"Steve"]) {
            [mapView removeOverlay:overlayToRemove];
        }
     }
  }
}
```

but I would like to have option to show/hide them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to let the user add the overlay back on to the screen you need to have a reference to it and call `addOverlay`. Will it only be one overlay they can do this to? Just add an instance variable called `removeableOverlay` and then when the person taps the button you won't need to hunt through all the overlays you can just that one

```
[mapView removeOverlay:removeableOverlay];
```

or

```
[mapView addOverlay:removeableOverlay];
```

according to whether it is there or not. You can keep track of that with a boolean, or the state of the button, or search for it in `mapView.overlays` (you'll only need to check equality not class and title). If it is there then you can remove it, if not you can add it.

Comment: Thanks @Craig for your reply, actually your answer seems to be the correct approach, but may be I am not getting it completely.

Please take some time to check my question where I have described everything in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640256/create-multiple-mkoverlays-from-web-service

Thanks again!