# Create multiple MKOverlays of polyline from locations coming via web-service

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

My app is real-time tracker, where multiple users are logged in and updating their location by sending their co-ordinates to our web service which is then called back let's after every 2 minutes to show all the users on my `MapView`.

Every time I get the locations of users from web service in `connectionDidFinishLoading` method, I am parsing, creating `polyline` through `pointsArray` and adding them to `overlay`:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *) connection
{
userLatitudeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
userLongitudeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
userIdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
userNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
userProfilePicArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
profilePicURLStringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

NSArray *trackingDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:empJsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

if ([trackingDict count] >= 2) {
    for (trackUsersCount = 0; trackUsersCount< trackingDict.count; trackUsersCount++) {
        NSLog(@"trackUsersCount %i", trackUsersCount);

        NSMutableArray *latlongArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        latlongArray = [[trackingDict objectAtIndex:trackUsersCount]objectForKey:@"latlong"];

        [userLongitudeArray removeAllObjects];
        [userLatitudeArray removeAllObjects];

        for (int i = 0; i<latlongArray.count; i++) {
            [userLatitudeArray addObject:[[latlongArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"lat"]];
            [userLongitudeArray addObject:[[latlongArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"long"]];

        }

        NSString *name = [[trackingDict objectAtIndex:trackUsersCount]objectForKey:@"user_firstName"];

        // ProfilePIC URL
        profilePicURLString = [[trackingDict objectAtIndex:trackUsersCount]objectForKey:@"user_profilePicture"];


        [userNameArray addObject:name];
        [profilePicURLStringArray addObject:profilePicURLString];

        int i;
        if (userLatitudeArray.count>1) {

            for (i = 0; i<userLatitudeArray.count; i++) {
                CLLocationCoordinate2D userLocation;
                userLocation.latitude = [[userLatitudeArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];
                userLocation.longitude = [[userLongitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
                MKMapPoint * pointsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)*userLongitudeArray.count);
                pointsArray[i] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(userLocation);
                polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:i];
                free(pointsArray);    
            }
            polyline.title = name;
            [mapView addOverlay:polyline];
        }
   }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to have control on each `polyline` created for each user, so I can change the color of it and hide/show them on click of a button (one to show/hide my track and the other for all other users), this is why I am adding title to it.
I can see now that I am adding `polyline` to the same `overlay`, which is wrong I believe. But  I don't know how many users will be there in web-service so can add multiple overlays of them.

Initially I thought I am able to remove a particular `polyline` with title but then I realised it is removing all as `polyline.title` property gets updated.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could collect an array of those tracks that relate to other users, and keep a single track for the current user. If you clean the array at the start of the `connectionDidFinishLoading` function and populate it where you are currently adding the overlays to the map, then you move the `addOverlay` to a new function that you call at the end.

```
- (void) resetMap
{
  if (showOtherTracks)
  {
      [mapView addOverlays:otherUserTracks];
  } else {
      [mapView removeOverlays:otherUserTracks];
  }
  if (showMyTrack)
  {
      [mapView addOverlay:myTrack];
  } else {
      [mapView removeOverlay:myTrack];
  }
}
```

You can also call this when ever the button is pressed and the state changes.

Comment: thanks I got that, but the problem here is if I want to control the color of polylines for each user I won't be able to do it unless I add separate overlay for each user, am I right?

Comment: Correct, and that's why otherUserTracks is an array of ploylines. Then in viewForOverlay you'll need to determine which is which and colour them accordingly.

Comment: is it possible to control color of each polyline in array, but within the same overlay? Please provide some sample, as I am confused how to do this when I have to show multiple polylines of different color in otherUserTracks?

Comment: The trick is they are not separate overlays. You add the array using `MKMapView addOverlays`. Then when `viewForOverlay` gets called it will be called for each item in that array, i.e. each ployline.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I hope I am not being pain in the back, but I think I am doing in the same way as you suggested, getting array, creating polyline and calling `mapView addOverlay:polyline` which will call `viewForOverlay` delegate method, the problem here is every time this method is called, it is overriding value of 'polyline' which is declared global and thus showing property color and the title which was defined last in the loop. 
What could be the optimized solution for this?

Comment: You are making a new MKPolyline each time you go to the loop, but that just changes the pointer "polyline", it doesn't change the ones already in the array. When your `viewforoverlay` gets called it will pass an `MKOverlay` as a parameter and that is your polyline. Get its title and then you can tell which line it is.